# Ignore multiple successive function calls in Typescript from within the function?

Tags: javascript, typescript, observable, handsontable

I am trying to implement [autocomplete using Handontable (Angular) by fetching data from the server](https://docs.handsontable.com/5.0.1/demo-autocomplete.html#strict-ajax) as the user types.

I notice the API calls are made every time the user input changes but I would like to limit the number of API calls by waiting 1 second for the user to stop typing before making the call.

I have done this in the past when I controlled the event by using [debounceTime](https://medium.com/aviabird/rxjs-reducing-number-of-api-calls-to-your-server-using-debouncetime-d71c209a4613) but not sure how to implement that here.

```
    ...
    column.source = function(query, callback) {
      $component.dataService.getValidValues().subscribe(
        arg => {
          callback(arg);
        },
        err => {
          ...
        }
      );
    }
    ...
```

Adding debounceTime(1000) here doesn't prevent multiple calls from happening.

`$component.dataService.getValidValues().debounceTime(1000).subscribe(...)`

Comment: Maybe because the `getValidValues` function is still making the request, and debounceTime is ensuring that the response isn't emitted. As in, the debounce time doesn't prevent the source from actually emitting the values, it just ensures the subscribers don't receive them.

Comment: And in this case, an http request only happens once. It seems the purpose of debounce time is to discard values that are emitted less than x seconds since the last emission, which (although don't quote me on this) seems a bit redundant for an observable that emits only once. I think it would be more effective to find a way to debounce the user input.

Comment: Exactly, I understand why the multiple calls are happening.
I just don't know how to debounce the user input, couldn't find it in the documentation I linked above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already explained by others you need to debounce the input. In your case this would be the invocation of the function.

One way to achieve that is using a subject that you create somewhere in your code:

```
const sourceRequest = new Subject();
sourceRequest.debounceTime(1000).subscribe(callback => {...});
```

The code you currently have inside `function(query, callback) {` goes into `subscribe`. The column definition is then changed to this:

```
column.source = function(query, callback) {
  sourceRequest.next(callback);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I wanted.
The only change I had to make was


    `column.source = function(query, callback) {
      sourceRequest.next({query: query, callback: callback});
    }`


Then I could use query and callback like this

    `sourceRequest.debounceTime(1000).subscribe((arg: any) => {
      // Use arg.query and arg.callback()
    });`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `.getValidValues()` is the function that makes the request to the remote server, you are debouncing the stream of events coming from this function. You want to debounce the stream of events coming from the user input, which limits the number of calls to `.getValidValues()`.

Try something like this

```
$component.dataService.debounceTime(1000).getValidValues().subscribe(...)
```

Comment: Since dataService is a class, debounceTime didn't work on it.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is for you to create a standard Javascript debounce function that wraps the function you are assigning to `column.source`, kind of like this:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mq9jyv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Thank you, I went with the other answer because it seemed a bit more straightforward for me.